# Upload different wheel distributions to PyPI

Tags: python, pip, packaging, pypi, python-wheel

I'm packaging a Python project with compiled extensions, and so I need to build different wheels for each platform (Linux and OSX) and Python versions (2.7 and 3.6). I can correctly create each wheel with:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

and then upload each one with `twine upload dist/package_name.whl`.

The problem is that when I try to install it with `pip`, it doesn't work in some Platforms/Python versions (OSX + Python 3.6 arises `No matching distribution found for package_name` for example).

I want to know how to configure it, so that `pip` can automatically detect which version of the wheel to install.

Thanks!